# Automate filling of attribute table using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, feature-count, autofields

I am new to QGIS and wish to automate my current process.

In my project I have to open the attribute table of the **batch_16** layer having 5 fields (*date, checked_by, td_created, td_catagor* and *op_comment*).

There are 4 additional layers also (*woody, sand, builtup, baresoil*)

The logic is, if I make any new features in any of these 4 layers after jumping to a grid tile of batch_16 layer as shown in the pic, then I have to assign some attributes to the selected grid tile attribute field as below:

td_catagor: what layers I have worked on after pressing "zoom to selected" to the grid tile and before moving to another selection. *woody - W, baresoil - B, sand - S, builtup - BU*. If there are more than one layers I have created new features then each letter should be separated by comma as depicted in the image.

How can I automate this process?

[image: Attributes]

[image: Layers]

Comment: have a look at variables: http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-2-12-part-1/

Comment: @KeshavSharma - It would be great if you mentioned ***how*** you automated your tasks (i.e. what expressions did you use). This could be beneficial for others :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to automate your workflow. (Tested on QGIS 3.4)

Add a last_updated field to your 4 layers and set a [default field value](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog218/index.html#feature-client-side-default-field-values) to the expression `now()`. This will ensure a timestamp is captured every time you make an edit to those layers.

The `td_created` and `td_catagor` should be setup as Virtual Fields so they are auto-updated based on an expression.

As you need to query another layer from your grid layer, you need to use the aggregate function. I am giving you example expression for 2 layers, *woody* and *sand* as the expression can get very long for the purpose of this answer. You can extend it for other layers. The expression assumes you have a field called `last_checked` in your grid layer.

For `td_created`, add a new virtual field with the following expression

```
if(
aggregate(
 layer:= 'woody',
 aggregate:='max',
 expression:=day(last_updated - attribute(@parent, 'last_checked')),
 filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 ) > 0 

 OR

 aggregate(
 layer:= 'sand',
 aggregate:='max',
 expression:=day(last_updated - attribute(@parent, 'last_checked')),
 filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
 ) > 0, 'Y', 'N')
```

Similarly, add another virtual field `td_categor` with the following expression

```
array_to_string(
array_remove_all(array(
  if(aggregate(
   layer:= 'woody',
   aggregate:='max',
   expression:=day(last_updated - attribute(@parent, 'last_checked')),
   filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
   ) > 0, 'woody', 'none'),
  if(aggregate(
   layer:= 'sand',
   aggregate:='max',
   expression:=day(last_updated - attribute(@parent, 'last_checked')),
   filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))
   ) > 0, 'sand', 'none')), 'none'))
```

This will add a comma-separated string with layer names like `woody,sand`

Now every-time you open the attribute table of the grid tile, these expressions will be evaluated and updated based on the timestamps in other layers.

I posted a more detailed explanation at https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/19/advanced-aggregate-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

I used AutoFields plugin in QGIS and entered expression as in the image and unchecked the "calculate expression on existing features."

[image: AutoFields]